# How to implement a Barcode decoder from local storage in react native

Tags: image, react-native, local-storage, barcode

How to implement a barcode decorder in images from loaclstorage. I currently take image from local storage using react native image picker now how can I decode the barcode from that image? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you use the open source libraries that do this

[jsQR](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR)

[React Native QRCodeLocalImage](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-qrcode-local-image)

Comment: Could you give me a sample eg of jsQR.

Comment: i tried like this
 ```const code = jsQR('./barCode.png', 262, 102);

    if (code) {
      console.log("Found QR code", code);
    }```
but shows Malformed data passed to binarizer.

Comment: which picture you trying?

Comment: This is indeed a problem I can't do either
You need to convert the image to a format Uint8ClampedArray
https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR#usage